# Find roots of a polynomial with coefficients all positive integers

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given the polynomial: $P(x) = x^7 + 9x^6 + 31x^5 + 55x^4 + 63x^3 + 55x^2 + 33x + 9 $
How do find it's roots ?

After a some time with try- error, I could verify: $ P(x) = (x + 1)^3 (x + 3)^2(x + i)(x − i) $

However is there a way to utilize the fact that all coefficient are positive, integer and that it is a monic polynominal?

As always any constructive help/hint/answer/recommendation for further reading  is appreciated.

Comment: The rational roots must be a divisor of $9$, so only $\pm1$ , $\pm3$ and $\pm9$ have to be checked. In this case, it is enough to completely factor the polynomial.

Comment: Furthermore, since all of the coefficients are positive, all of the (real) roots must be negative, leaving just $-1, -3, -9$ to be checked.

Comment: @Peter That's if we're only looking for rational roots.

Comment: @Farnight True, but it's usually a good place to start looking. If you can't reduce the degree pretty fast, you rarely have a shot at finding the roots of a 7th degree polynomial.

Comment: The roots $-i$ and $i$ are difficult to detect only looking at the original polynomial.

Comment: @Peter I feared so :/
I guess the "safest" approach is, first checking -1,-3

I think one could also argue: -3 must be a root of degree 2, because prod of all roots equals 9 

Then you have theoretically 5 roots left, you can further deduce, there must be -i,+i roots, because the order of -1 roots can't be odd

Comment: However this does not help too much finding: the order of (x^2+1) or (x+1)

Comment: Just check the reduced polynomial again for the roots or look at the derivations to detect multiple roots.

Comment: You cannot deduce that $-3$ must be a multiple root because the product can also be $9$, if the other roots are irrational (or even complex). By the way, the product is $-9$ because the degree is odd.

Comment: Yeah, my comment was rushed and wrong. srry

Answer (score 1):

It's usually worth trying the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) which says that any rational root of the polynomial 
$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$$
can be written in the form $p/q$ where $p$ is a factor of $a_0$ and $q$ is a factor or $a_n$.

In your case this leads us to check for $\pm1$, $\pm3$, $\pm9$ as roots, and as Travis points out in the comments, the positive ones can be easily discarded. Presumably you would start with checking $-1$ and upon finding that it works you would factor out the $(x+1)$ term(s) so you don't have huge powers for subsequent checks.

After dealing with the rational roots in this case you get down to a quadratic - easy enough to solve the rest.

The key point here is to try finding rational roots first and then worry about other solutions.